# Como usar Angular input mask

Tags: angularjs, ionic, mask

Eu uso AngularJs e Ionic e estou tentando usar este [Input Mask](https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks), mas não sei bem como fazer. Eu sigo os passos e mesmo assim aparece este erro: [Erro Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.13%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dteste%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.3.13%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dteste%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Error%2520(native)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fcode.ionicframework.com%252F1.0.0-rc.5%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.min.js%253A37%253A417%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fcode.ionicframework.com%252F1.0.0-rc.5%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.min.js%253A52%253A412%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520a%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fcode.ionicframework.com%252F1.0.0-rc.5%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.min.js%253A52%253A53)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fcode.ionicframework.com%252F1.0.0-rc.5%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.min.js%253A52%253A296%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fcode.ionicframework.com%252F1.0.0-rc.5%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.min.js%253A66%253A46%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520s%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fcode.ionicframework.com%252F1.0.0-rc.5%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.min.js%253A38%253A302)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fcode.ionicframework.com%252F1.0.0-rc.5%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.min.js%253A65%253A399)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Fcode.ionicframework.com%252F1.0.0-rc.5%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.min.js%253A66%253A63%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520s%2520(http%253A%252F%252Fcode.ionicframework.com%252F1.0.0-rc.5%252Fjs%252Fionic.bundle.min.js%253A38%253A302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Error%20(native)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js:37:417%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js:66:320%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js:38:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js:65:399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js:66:63%0A%20%20%20%20at%20s%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js:38:302)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js:65:399)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20ab%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js:69:135)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20d%20(http:%2F%2Fcode.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js:48:381/%22Erro%20Angular%22).

Referências no index.html:

```
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/services.js"></script>
<script src="../angular-input-masks/releases/angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'ui.utils.masks','starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])
```

Comment: Qual o erro que mostra pra você? No teu console.

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$injector/modulerr?p0=starter&p1=Error%3…code.ionicframework.com%2F1.0.0-rc.5%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.min.js%3A48%3A381)

Comment: Acho que faltou adicionar o js do ionic

Comment: Ja tem, está logo acima. Não coloquei aqui para não ficar muito grande.<!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-rc.5/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que a referência ao arquivo `angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js` estava fora da pasta `www`, tornando o arquivo inacessivel.
Desta forma funcionou.

**Forma certa**

```
<script src="mask/angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
```

**Forma errada**

```
<script src="../angular-input-masks/releases/angular-input-masks-standalone.min.js"></script>
```

Pelo menos aqui deu certo.

Comment: https://github.com/assisrafael/angular-input-masks não existe a pasta /angular-input-masks/

Comment: No meu pacote tinha, da uma olhada no seu para algo equivalente.